# Why cant we see classes folder of a Dynamic Web Application from Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I have created a New --> Dynamic Web Project from Eclipse IDE , 
Modified the Java Build Path for default Output folder as 
Ramesh/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes

But now , Why cant we see classes folder of a Dynamic Web Application from Eclipse IDE ??
Please see the screen shot of it .

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2yjvx3d&s=7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how the project explorer's filters are configured by default.

Click on the little triangle at the top right of the project explorer view, then select "Customize View...", and uncheck "Java output folders", and you'll see it.

[image]

Comment: I cant find that , Could you please provide a screen shot of it . Ayway i have installed Easy Explorer jar plug in for this .Thanks for your time .